# Enable Device's Camera App in Android Management API Policy

Tags: android-management-api

My app calls the device's camera app using:

```
Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    if (pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        File file = null;
        try {
            file = createImageFile();
            Log.d(TAG, "created imagefile ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        Log.d(TAG, "openCamera: " + photoUri);
        pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);


        startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
```

When using the app in a provisioned device with "cameraDisabled": false I still cannot load the camera.

My policy is:

{
  "applications": [{
        "packageName": "**************",
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }],
  "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true,
  "addUserDisabled": true,
    "adjustVolumeDisabled": true,
    "outgoingCallsDisabled": true,
  "locationMode": "HIGH_ACCURACY",
  "cameraDisabled": false,
    "screenCaptureDisabled": true,
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
  "wifiConfigDisabled": false,
    "dataRoamingDisabled": false,
    "smsDisabled": true,
    "factoryResetDisabled": false,
  "uninstallAppsDisabled": true,
    "tetheringConfigDisabled": true,
    "shareLocationDisabled": false,
    "funDisabled": true,
  "appAutoUpdatePolicy": "WIFI_ONLY",
  "systemUpdate": {
        "type": "WINDOWED",
        "startMinutes": 10,
        "endMinutes": 1430
    },
  "kioskCustomLauncherEnabled":true,
  "kioskCustomization": {
        "deviceSettings": "SETTINGS_ACCESS_ALLOWED"
    }
  }

UPDATE: 
I ended up using the the CameraX library to create my own camera instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have probably disabled system apps during enrollment in the QR code.

Now for your question, you will have to find the `package name` of the `default camera app` of the device and just enable it in the policy.

For example, Snapdragon Camera is the default on my Zebra devices :

```
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "org.codeaurora.snapcam",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know the camera app would be different for each device brand but with system apps disabled, this is the way that I've been using.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.